# How can I trace where an email originated from

Tags: windows-live-mail

I have been receiving abusive emails and would like to trace the original location. I have gone through the email header but unfortunaly this does not show the x-originating-Ip address. Is there any other way to trace the sender?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy thing to do.  It is technically possible, but requires work and effort that would come from the originating mail provider and the ISP providing the service to the person sending the abusive email.  Providers usually will not give out this information without a court order or some serious breach of their terms of service.

This is all assuming the person isnt using an anonymous remailer, or using unprotected WiFi, or many of the other things that can be hiding his identity or location.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, highlight the email, right click, at the bottom hit properties, hit details.

Don't know if this is what you want or not.

Comment: Since you mentioned yourself you're unsure of this answer, don't you think it might serve better as a comment?